# Telegram Bot модератор

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delete_links(message: types.Message):
username = message.from_user.username
adminid = [admin.user.id for admin in await    bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=message.chat.id)]
if message.from_user.id not in adminid:

    if '@' in message.text:  # Удаление сообщений с тегами (@тег)
        await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"@{username}, лучше тэгай на бумаге <3.")

    for entity in message.entities:  # Удаление сообщений с ссылками
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"@{username} извини, но ссылки запрещены (")
```

Ребят столкнулся с проблемой.
Данный бот удаляет ссылки и теги в чате
Чат привязан к каналу.

Я делаю публикацию в которой есть ссылка, сам телеграмм автоматом кидает этот пост в чат, но бот не знает канал и удаляет ссылку, а тем самым полностью пост, и в канале пропадают коменты. Как решить эту проблему?

Спасибо!

Comment: Не выкладывайте код скриншотом, выложите текстом

Comment: Не сталкивались с такой проблемой?